# How do I enable syntax highlighting for a large C# file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I'm used to using Visual Studio 2017, but need to view, and possibly edit, a large generated C# file which crashes Visual Studio (both 2015 and 2017) if I open it.

The VS crash is a separate issue, but I have found I can open the file in Visual Studio Code and at least view the source without Code crashing.

However, the normal syntax highlighting seems to be turned off, although I have the recommended "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)" extension from Microsoft installed and smaller files correctly show syntax highlighting.

As almost a complete novice in using VSCode, how do I enable highlighting when it doesn't get turned on by default? For info, the generated file is about 1.1 million lines of C#.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature : https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34240

Comment: Thanks, at least I now know. I've added a comment that even for my 1.1 million line file, assuming 6 token per line only adds 53Mb to the memory footprint. Not unreasonable on a PC with 64Gb or RAM - it should be user selectable.

Comment: PS: I supposed I could download the source and build a custom version. :)

Comment: I can't imagine why one code file would be so big. Very poorly structured program.

Comment: As I said, it's generated code. It's actually the OData client classes generated from Microsoft Dynamics 365 for Finance and Operations OData interface by Microsoft's OData V4 Client Generator (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator, https://github.com/OData/odata.net). As a result, I have no control over the structuring of the file.Note that attempting to break this generated file up into smaller pieces has previously failed - it then doesn't compile because it runs out of memory to store user strings.

Answer (score 4):

This could work:

```
"editor.largeFileOptimizations": false,
"files.maxMemoryForLargeFilesMB": 16384,
```